# Display the most selected Items by the User - laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table called usuarios_tienen_videojuegos with  the user_id and the videogames_id .
I want to display the most selected video games by the users. Right now, I’m displaying the video games IDs but I also need to display the video games names , the names are in the table Videogames. How can I achieve that?

**Controller**

```
public function usuariosVista()
{
    $videogames = Videogames::with(['plataforma', 'generos', 'categoria', 'numJugadores', ‘users])->get();
    $users = User::with('usersVideogames')->get();

    $PopularGames = DB::table('usuarios_tienen_videojuegos')
    ->select('videogames_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as seleccionados_count'))
    ->groupBy('videogames_id')
    ->orderByDesc('seleccionados_count')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();

    return view('admin.videojuegos.usuarios', [
        'videogames' => $videogames,
        ‘users’ => $users,
        'PopularGames' => $PopularGames,
    ]);
}
```

**HTML**

```
@foreach($PopularGames as $game)
    <li>{{ $game->videogames_id }} (Selected by {{ $game->seleccionados_count }} users)</li>
@endforeach
```

**User class**

```
public function usersVideogames()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(VideoJuegos::class, 'usuarios_tienen_videojuegos', 'user_id', 'videogames_id');
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [counting related models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) will be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Try modify the $PopularGames query to include the video game names:

```
$PopularGames = DB::table('usuarios_tienen_videojuegos')
    ->select('usuarios_tienen_videojuegos.videogames_id', 'videogames.name', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as seleccionados_count'))
    ->join('videogames', 'usuarios_tienen_videojuegos.videogames_id', '=', 'videogames.id')
    ->groupBy('usuarios_tienen_videojuegos.videogames_id', 'videogames.name')
    ->orderByDesc('seleccionados_count')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```